# How can I install qemu on a VM without Internet access?

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm generating a virtual machine that will (eventually) be used to run a proof of concept web server. I'm running RH7.4 for my host and 7.2 for my VM.

I'm following [Red Hat's official](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/chap-qemu_guest_agent) instructions to set up a VM using Virtual Machine manager, but I'm unable to complete the installation of qemu guest on my VM. Giving the command

```
yum install qemu-guest-agent
```

returns an error informing me that I need to register subscription manager. However, it's impossible to register it without internet access. The host machine has qemu guest installed already, and I'd love to find a way that I can just transfer it to the VM, if at all possible. Surely there's a way to handle this without internet access, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to extract package with dependencies from you machine, but you can actually do the following if your primary machine go over internet:

```
yum install yum-utils
yumdownloader --resolve httpd
```

this will download the package with all dependencies in your current directory, of course change httpd with qemu then you can transfer everything to your machine with scp command like that:

```
scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory
```

let us know if it works!